# mat-tab-group doesn't show styles for default tab selected

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have three tabs:`label1`, `label2` and `label3`. Inside each one of them there is another set of tabs. Now by default `label1` shows the selected style as well as `tab1` inside of it. Now once I click on another label like `label 2` another set of tab loads but none of them shows tab label highlighted. Same goes for `label3`. I explicitly have to click on the tabs to see the styles.

Please find a link to the issue:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tyjslw?file=app/tabs-template-label-example.html

Answer (score 7):

They are only adding css on focus , so if you want to add style on active ,you can achieve that by :

In Component Css :

```
.mat-tab-label-active{
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Component Side add :

```
encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-tab-active)**

Comment: It looks a bit odd when I click on the content after clicking on one of the tabs. It has normal background but when I click on the content somewhere it turns to red. Also when I switch tabs it shows red background on the tab that I left for a a split second. Any workarounds?

Comment: @AakashThakur , check now.

Comment: It looks better now. Did you change something?

Comment: Css , opacity change

Comment: Okay. I will upvaote your answer but will wait for some other inputs as well. I mean if someone can come up with a better fix.

Comment: @AakashThakur , Sure If not then please accept the answer also :) , Happy Coding btw.

Comment: Yeah sure. You too.

Comment: One quick question vivek. Why did you use `ViewEncapsulation`? Does that style has to be globally available?

Comment: You can make it global by putting it in main css , but I did that for the compoenent part only , as It won't affect the main styling.

Comment: Hey Vivek. But as far as I have read `ViewEncapsulation.None` affects the rest of the styles of the app. Its `Native` and `Emulated` that does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163931/discussion-between-vivek-doshi-and-aakash-thakur).

Answer (score 0):

There are not only some CSS changes when selecting a tab but also an ink bar that moves to the selected tab.

I had a similar problem when my toolbar wasn't visible during the initialization process: I had a toolbar inside a [sidenav](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview) that is closed by default and when I opened it, the default selected tab wasn't highlighted.

A possibility to do this the proper way is using the `realignInkBar()` method of [`MatTabGroup`](https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/api#MatTabGroup). In your case you should call this method for the correct `mat-tab-group` element when changing a tab on the main `mat-tab-group`.